# Github actions cache behaviour in docker/build-push-action@v3

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

We have a workflow which includes the following step to build and push our image - docker/build-push-action@v3:

```
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ inputs.image_name && format(',{0}:{1}', inputs.image_name, steps.tags.outputs.tag1) || '' }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
          provenance: false
          build-args: |
            ${{ secrets.build-args }}
            ${{ inputs.build-args }}
          secrets: |
            ${{secrets.build-secrets}}
          ssh: |
            default=${{ env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}
```

In the Dockerfile we install a few private python packages, here's a shortened version of our Dockerfile showing relevant bits:

```
FROM python:3.10


RUN pip install -U pip \
    && pip install 'poetry>=1.0.0' \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install $(test "$BUILD_ENV" == ci && echo "--no-dev") --no-interaction --no-ansi

ARG GIT_HASH

# Install python packages
RUN --mount=type=ssh \
    mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && poetry run pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/**REDACTED**/python-files.git#egg=**REDACTED**&subdirectory=**REDACTED**" \
    && poetry run pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/**REDACTED**/python-files.git#egg=**REDACTED**&subdirectory=**REDACTED**"


CMD python main.py
```

We use `ARG GIT_HASH`, this has been added to trigger a cache miss when installing the python packages immediately after [as per the official docs](https://%20https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/), to ensure a fresh up to date copy of the packages are installed (and other parts of the docker build process before this use the github actions cache).

However this doesn't appear to be working and the image is still being built using older versions of the packages.

It only works if I completely comment out the `cache-from` and `cache-to` lines to stop using the github actions cache.

Snippet from Docker build log on github actions:

```
#12 [5/7] RUN --mount=type=ssh     mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && poetry run pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/**REDACTED**/python-files.git#egg=**REDACTED**&subdirectory=**REDACTED**" && poetry run pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/**REDACTED**/python-files.git#egg=**REDACTED**&subdirectory=**REDACTED**" && poetry run pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/**REDACTED**/
#12 extracting sha256:7d300de960bdd6899dd0ea1687b4d4ab68198341d0e60957463099eafd9e1eab done
#12 extracting sha256:0fc41ee805e3e6029f57a8202d1dcb6a5b15701070236117318a4ff67c0735f2
#12 extracting sha256:0fc41ee805e3e6029f57a8202d1dcb6a5b15701070236117318a4ff67c0735f2 0.2s done
#12 DONE 19.7s

#13 [6/7] COPY app /app
#13 DONE 1.8s

#14 [7/7] WORKDIR /app
#14 DONE 0.0s

#15 exporting to image
#15 exporting layers 0.1s done
```

Any ideas why this could be?